# Android/iOS: How to use existing microsoft account when using MSAL

Tags: android, ios, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

When using MSAL library for authentication the app is redirecting the user to a webpage where they have to login with microsoft account. If the user already having Outlook or some other app installed then is there a way to get that login info like how FB app does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSAL works best on iOS if the user has installed and configured the Microsoft Authenticator app.  MSAL will launch that app instead of a web browser and the user can just tap their account to login.

If the device is managed by an MDM then you can [enable the enterprise SSO component>(https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc#microsoft-enterprise-sso-plug-in-for-apple-devices) to further simplify the login process.

Without the Authenticator app there is no way for your app to get any existing account authentication details.

Comment: I know how the authenticator app works. But that still adds a step where it you have to enter the authenticator code to login. Ideally I want my app to have a seamless flow like how login with fb works in most apps.

Comment: The only way to get a seamless flow is to implement the SSO extension via an MDM, otherwise there is no way for the app to get authentication details from outside of the sandbox

Comment: So far didn't find anything relevant so accepting yours as the answer.

Comment: Can a general public app work with MDM? i.e the app when logged in from a personal microsoft account will make the user type username and password and the same app when used by an user whos device is enrolled in his own companys MDM will auto login. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes.  The sso component of Microsoft Authenticator is enabled by an MDM distributes policy. Without that policy the sso extension is not enabled.

Comment: I just did that and did SSO and tried to access the users calendar using graph API and got "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound" exception

Comment: Did you use the tenant specific laugh endpoint? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53566481/microsoft-graph-api-organizationfromtenantguidnotfound-using-msal alternatively you can try making your application a cross-tenant application in the azure portal.

Comment: The problem was with a Godaddy issued office 365 and MDM having some issues. We created a new office 365 subscription directly with Microsoft and its working good. Thanks for the help

Comment: Does this sso plug-in exist for Android? I couldn't find by googling.

Comment: I don't believe Android has enterprise sso plug-in support.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but:

- Azure AD messages are mostly standards based so you don't have to use MSAL libraries
- You may get a better mobile solution with AppAuth libraries

Rather than a web page you could use the in app browser solutions, which feel integrated and have some good UX features:

- Chrome Custom Tabs on Android
- ASWebAuthenticationSession on iOS

In case any of this is useful, here are some links of mine, including code samples you can run:

- [Kotlin app for Android](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/)
- [SwiftUI app for iOS](https://authguidance.com/2020/02/22/ios-code-sample-overview/)

Comment: The problem is not just moving to a browser window. In Google and FB you can actually just choose and existing account and not have the user input the email and password again. Which adds a lot of user experience.